# Can someone tell me how to sum only some of items nested in my JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am not very proud of this codeㅠㅠ I have 6000 objects in the array and would like to sum only 10 items from the array. Now I am putting ten coding blocks to the program.

Someone can tell me how to make it look like programing?

`<Text style={styles.text}>[{Number((items.find( x => x.id === indexTwoId+101).as==='1'?'1':'0'))+Number((items.find( x => x.id === indexTwoId+102).as==='1'?'1':'0'))+Number((items.find( x => x.id === indexTwoId+103).as==='1'?'1':'0'))+Number((items.find( x => x.id === indexTwoId+104).as==='1'?'1':'0'))+Number((items.find( x => x.id === indexTwoId+105).as==='1'?'1':'0'))+Number((items.find( x => x.id === indexTwoId+106).as==='1'?'1':'0'))+Number((items.find( x => x.id === indexTwoId+107).as==='1'?'1':'0'))+Number((items.find( x => x.id === indexTwoId+108).as==='1'?'1':'0'))+Number((items.find( x => x.id === indexTwoId+109).as==='1'?'1':'0'))+Number((items.find( x => x.id === indexTwoId+110).as==='1'?'1':'0'))}/10]</Text>`

My array is as follows;

````
    count: 1,
    categories: [
        {id:1,as:0},
        {id:2,as:0},
        {id:3,as:0},
        {id:4,as:0},
        {id:5,as:0},
        {id:6,as:0},
        {id:7,as:0},
        {id:8,as:0},
        {id:9,as:0},
        {id:10,as:0},
.
.
.
.]}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have experience with React, but in "regular" JS you might do something like this:

```
let sum = items.reduce((item, total) => {
    if (item.id < indexTwoId + 101 || item.id > indexTwoId + 110) return total;
    if (item.as === '1') return total + 1;
    return total;
}, 0)
```

You can probably "translate" it to a single line with ternary operators.

EDIT:
If you just want to count items by criteria then:

```
items.filter(x => x.id >= indexTwoId + 101 && x.id <= indexTwoId + 110 && x.as === '1').length
```

Comment: @TheMaster yes, and it will keep running through all array elements, to give the number of items that qualify by the id constraint and have an 'as' member that equals '1'. Try this: `[ 1, 2, 3 ].reduce((num, total) => { if (num < 2) return total; return total + num; });`. This yields 5.

Comment: Thank you very much fist of all. The red screen says; Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, as}.

Comment: You're right. But even then, yours will count it all, while op's will count only the first item with id 101, 102 and so on... right? If ids are unique, it probably shouldn't matter

Comment: @TheMaster are you referring to the first or second snippet? what do you mean by "count all"? do you mean that the result would be different from the op's, or that the internal "process" would be different? (supposedly less efficient)

Comment: @Lee I'm not sure I can help with React-specific issues but I can try if you post a fuller code and/or screenshot of what you see (with the error, etc.)

Comment: If `items` is `[
        {id:101,as:1},
        {id:101,as:1}]`,op's code will count 1, while yours will count 2.(`indexTwoId`==0)

Comment: @TheMaster yes, you're right, it will count "duplicates". There may also be other differences. For example, I suspect that with the op's code, `[ {id:101,as:0}, {id:101,as:1}]` may not be counted at all, whereas with mine it would.

Comment: @obe Thanks a lot. and Thank TheMaster too. Your second code works perfect saving a day for me. Thank you.